# Distance measures that preserve Pythagoras' theorem but break the triangle inequality

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, information-geometry

In information geometry, we can think of the Kullback-Leibler divergence as being "something like a squared distance."

The sense of this is that if we have three probability measures, $P$, $Q$ and $R$, on the same support, then it may or may not be the case that $D(Q\|R) + D(P\|Q) = D(P\|R)$. If this is the case, then the "line segment" from $R$ to $Q$ is *orthogonal* to the one from $Q$ to $P$ in a meaningful and useful sense. (I put "line segment" in quotes because there are subtleties about dual geodesics that I don't want to go into - the important thing here is that this equation defines a notion of orthogonality between the three points $P$, $Q$ and $R$, which need not be asymptotically close to each other.) This equation looks like the Pythagorean theorem, which says that if $PQ$ and $QR$ are orthogonal in a Euclidean space, then $d^2(R,Q) + d^2(Q,P) = d^2(R,P)$, where $d^2$ is the squared Euclidean distance.

On the other hand, neither the K-L divergence nor its square root are metrics, and they both break the triangle inequality as well as symmetry. So we seem to be looking at a kind of generalisation of the notion of metric, which is in some ways weaker than the usual (Lawvere) generalised metric, because it doesn't require the triangle inequality, but which is also stronger than most generalisations of a metric (and indeed the notion of metric itself), because it includes a notion of orthogonality and a generalisation of the Pythagorean theorem, even for points that are not asymptotically near each other.

My question is whether something like this has been studied in a general form, outside of information geometry. I'm being deliberately vague about what the meaning of "orthogonal" should be exactly, so as not to constrain answers. My interest is just in whether geometry has been generalised in anything this way, outside of information geometry.

Ideally, if this can be / has been done, it would be nice to see something like this defined in a way that doesn't assume an underlying differentiable space, in the same way that no notion of differentiability is needed in the definition of a metric.

Comment: It might be some sort of pre-metric (to be given category-theoretic interpretation yet): as explained e. g. [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Fisher_information_metric), with parameter-variable families $P(\theta)$ of distributions the Hessian$$g_{jk}(\theta_0):=\left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial_j\partial_k}\right|_{\theta=\theta_0}D(P(\theta)||P(\theta_0))$$produces a Riemannian metric

Comment: Indeed, the KL divergence yields a Riemannian metric if we consider infinitesimally small displacements. But the interesting thing is, the orthogonality property is defined and is useful/meaningful even for points that are far away from one another. This is the aspect I'm most interested in - the way it seems "squared distance like" even over large distances, where it doesn't behave like a metric. (Thank you for the useful comment.)